# What is Eclipse's Ctrl+H shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

In `Intellij IDEA`, how to search a string or a keyword in all project files as we can do in `Eclipse` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> command?

Comment: not sure but you can change intellij's bindings to mirror Eclipses

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F will help u. (Notes you can custom module for searching :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To search in workspace you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

To find in path <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is useful

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search across the project

Answer (score 2):

```
 Ctrl + H = "Type Hierarchy" view = shows a tree of parent and 
 child classes of this class.

 Ctrl + Shift + A = "It does a search as you type through all the commands 
 in intellij. Not only that but when you find the command you want it also 
 displays the corresponding shortcut key next to it!"
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Hope this will helpful to you !

Answer (score 2):

For navigating to a class by name (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the above solutions and also the link which is mentioned in here for more useful shortcuts with intellij

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/

Hope this helps
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Shortcut you are searching for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

In the Find In Path dialog box displayed, specify the following options:

1. The text to find.
2. Type the text explicitly, or specify a pattern using a regular expression, or select a previously used piece of text or a pattern from the recent history drop-down list.
3. If you specify the search pattern through a regular expression, use the $n format in back references (to refer to a previously found and saved pattern).
4. Search scope (project , module or directory).
5. Search options (case sensitivity, whole words, and regular
   expressions).

Then Click **Find**.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in *IntelliJ IDEA*
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in *Eclipse*